# Set Contains() method returning false, Map.get() return null

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a text file and a CSV file. When my application starts I read the text file and CSV file and put it in `List`, `Set` or `Map`. Here is what I am doing:

```
public class App {

    private static List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static List<String> zipCodeList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Set<String> citySet = new HashSet<>();
    private static Set<String> stateSet = new HashSet<>();
    private static Map<String, String> zipCityMap = new HashMap<>();
    private static Map<String, String> zipStateMap = new HashMap<>();

    static {

        String nameFile = "Names.txt";
        String zipCodeFile = "ZipCodes.csv";
        try {
            Path nameFilePath = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(nameFile).toURI());
            namesList = getNamesList(nameFilePath);
            System.out.println(namesList.contains("Kristina"));

            Path csvFilePath = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(zipCodeFile).toURI());

            List<String> csvList = getCsvList(csvFilePath);

            citySet = getCitySet(csvList);
            System.out.println(citySet.contains("Reddick"));

            zipCodeList = getZipCodeList(csvList);
            System.out.println(zipCodeList.contains("00210"));

            stateSet = getStateSet(csvList);
            System.out.println(stateSet.contains("KY"));

            zipCityMap = getZipCityMap(csvList);

            zipStateMap = getZipStateMap(csvList);

            String zipCity = zipCityMap.get(83214);
            String zipState = zipStateMap.get(83214);

            System.out.println(zipCity);
            System.out.println(zipState);   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    private static List<String> getNamesList(Path nameFilePath) throws IOException {

        List<String> namesList = null;

        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(nameFilePath)) {
        namesList = reader
            .lines()
            .map(line -> line)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return namesList;
    }

    private static List<String> getZipCodeList(List<String> csvList) throws IOException {

        List<String> zipCodeList = csvList
            .stream()
            .map(line -> line.split(","))
            .map(arr -> arr[0])
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return zipCodeList;
    }

    private static Set<String> getCitySet(List<String> csvList) throws IOException {

        Set<String> citySet = getSet(csvList, 1);
        return citySet;
    }

    private static Set<String> getStateSet(List<String> csvList) throws IOException {

        Set<String> stateSet = getSet(csvList, 2);
        return stateSet;
    }

    private static Set<String> getSet(List<String> csvList, int columnIndex) throws IOException {

        Set<String> stateSet = csvList
            .stream()
            .map(line -> line.split(","))
            .map(arr -> arr[columnIndex])
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        return stateSet;
    }

    private static Map<String, String> getZipCityMap(List<String> csvList) throws IOException {

        Map<String, String> zipCityMap = getMap(csvList, 0, 1);
        return zipCityMap;
    }

    private static Map<String, String> getZipStateMap(List<String> csvList) throws IOException {

        Map<String, String> zipStateMap = getMap(csvList, 0, 2);
        return zipStateMap;
    } 

    private static Map<String, String> getMap(List<String> csvList, int zipColumnIndex, int columnIndex) throws IOException {

        Map<String, String> zipStateMap = csvList
            .stream()
            .map(line -> line.split(","))
            .map(arr -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(arr[zipColumnIndex], arr[columnIndex]))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> entry.getValue()));

        return zipStateMap;
    }

    private static List<String> getCsvList(Path csvFilePath) throws IOException {

        List<String> csvList = null;
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(csvFilePath)) {
        csvList =  reader
                .lines()
                .skip(1)
                .filter(line -> line.indexOf(',') != -1)
                .map(line -> line)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return csvList;
    }
}
```

The problem is `contains()` method return `false`. When I try to get value from `zipCityMap` or `zipStateMap` I get `null`. Although while debugging when I put cursor to any of the set or map or List I saw the values there, but it is printing false or null. Why it is printing this even values are there ? How can I solve this problem?

### Edit

Names.txt

```
Kristina
Paige
Sherri
Gretchen
Karen
Patrick
Elsie
Hazel
Malcolm
Dolores
Francis
Sandy
```

ZipCodes.csv

```
"zip","city","state","latitude","longitude","timezone","dst"
"00210","Portsmouth","NH","43.005895","-71.013202","-5","1"
"00211","Portsmouth","NH","43.005895","-71.013202","-5","1"
"00212","Portsmouth","NH","43.005895","-71.013202","-5","1"
"00213","Portsmouth","NH","43.005895","-71.013202","-5","1"
"00214","Portsmouth","NH","43.005895","-71.013202","-5","1"
"00215","Portsmouth","NH","43.005895","-71.013202","-5","1"
"00501","Holtsville","NY","40.922326","-72.637078","-5","1"
"00544","Holtsville","NY","40.922326","-72.637078","-5","1"
"00601","Adjuntas","PR","18.180103","-66.74947","-4","0"
"00602","Aguada","PR","18.363285","-67.18024","-4","0"
"00603","Aguadilla","PR","18.448619","-67.13422","-4","0"
"00604","Aguadilla","PR","18.498987","-67.13699","-4","0"
"00605","Aguadilla","PR","18.465162","-67.141486","-4","0"
"00606","Maricao","PR","18.182151","-66.9588","-4","0"
"00607","Aguas Buenas","PR","18.256995","-66.104657","-4","0"

"00609","Aibonito","PR","18.142002","-66.273278","-4","0"
"00610","Anasco","PR","18.288319","-67.13604","-4","0"
"00611","Angeles","PR","18.279531","-66.80217","-4","0"
"00612","Arecibo","PR","18.449732","-66.69879","-4","0"
"00613","Arecibo","PR","18.458093","-66.732732","-4","0"
"00614","Arecibo","PR","18.429675","-66.674506","-4","0"
"00615","Arroyo","PR","17.96977","-66.061459","-4","0"
"00616","Bajadero","PR","18.426748","-66.67669","-4","0"
"00617","Barceloneta","PR","18.455499","-66.55575","-4","0"
"00618","Barranquitas","PR","18.185463","-66.305827","-4","0"
"00622","Boqueron","PR","18.003125","-67.16745","-4","0"
"00623","Cabo Rojo","PR","18.08643","-67.15222","-4","0"
"00624","Penuelas","PR","18.055399","-66.72602","-4","0"
"00625","Caguas","PR","18.232109","-66.039087","-4","0"
"00626","Caguas","PR","18.235003","-66.037318","-4","0"
"00627","Camuy","PR","18.435246","-66.85644","-4","0"
```

Comment: Have you debugged your collections to verify that they're actually being filled with the expected data? `contains` and `get` are most definitely not broken, so the issue is likely elsewhere.

Comment: Also, creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help narrow the problem down for others to understand what exactly the issue is.  Furthermore, on questions like these, it's likely that you'll be able to solve the issue yourself when minimizing the problem.

Comment: Yes this is the problem. I debug the code, and while debugging values are there, they are filled properly, but still getting null and false. Don't know why ..... ?

Comment: Post an excerpt from input files (several lines incluing "Reddick", "00210" and "KY" would be fine). Also why so complex `getNamesList` method? Why not simply using `return Files.readAllLines(nameFilePath)`?

Comment: Check my edit please. Sample data is there .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes from the input strings. You may do it modifying the `getSet` method like this:

```
Set<String> stateSet = csvList
    .stream()
    .map(line -> line.split(","))
    .map(arr -> arr[columnIndex].replace("\"", ""))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The same should be done in `getMap` method. Note that there are plenty of libraries which can properly read CSV files (for example, [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)). It's better to use libraries to read well-known file formats as there can be some subtle things you may not aware of.

Comment: Ah .... Superb after reading it contains `""` and I was matching without `""`. ... Thank you so much. I was stuck. May thanks to you. Actually I want to do it in Java 8 Streams way :). Now it is working fine :)